# Validate form have all the textfield/combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any way to validate a form to see if it has the necessary textfields or combo box on the form? my form has a form id and the textfields/combobox have names associated with each fields.

I've tried querying the combo box that should not be there but i get undefined.

Comment: without seeing the code, can only say, it can be done with jQuery

Comment: don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Do it with PHP validation or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) on your form:

```
form.down('field[name="text1"]')
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q4n

Comment: how is that validating if that particular field is valid or exist? plus I have a couple different forms at the same time.

Comment: It only verifies existence of fields, not validity (as per the wording of your original question).
The quoted code will return `null` if that particular field does not exist. If you have a have a look at the fiddle (open JavaScript console) you'll see.

Comment: so if i have a form that has a Id = "1". componentquery.query(?)

Comment: If you know the ID of your form, you can retrieve it with [`Ext.getCmp(ID)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp).

Comment: your fiddle returns true all the time whether or not the field exist. Is there anyway to return false if it does not exist?

Comment: The fiddle does not return anything. It writes "exists" in the console if the field exists, or "does not exist" otherwise. Nevertheless, you can get boolean return from the solution code by adding double exclamation mark: `!!form.down('field[name="text1"]')`.

Comment: It would return the correct boolean to the console, but i want to return it to a variable because once i pass it to a var, it will return always true:               var ok = Ext.each(names, function(name) {
return console.log(name + ' ' + (!!form.down('field[name=' + name + ']'))); console.log(ok) //returns always true.

Comment: That `Ext.each` is merely to show how checking existence works for a range of names in loop. In your case, use `var ok = !!form.down('field[name="text1"]');`. Substitute `form` with the actual reference to your form (e.g. `Ext.getCmp(FormID)` or something like that), and `text1` with the name of the field you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
'itemId': 'myForm'
```

to your form view.
Then use

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myForm')[0].isValid()
```

to see if the form is valid.

Comment: I want to excess the form then validate the fields if they are valid!